# How does EAV compare to RDF?

Tags: rdf, entity-attribute-value

Is [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) a superset of the [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model?

I'm looking into [EAV Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214018/entity-attribute-value-eav-frameworks) and it seems that many RDF Frameworks could be used to provide EAV Frameworks.

E.g. With an RDF store and something like [LinqToRDF](http://code.google.com/p/linqtordf/) would I have myself a ready-to-go .NET EAV Framework?

Comment: If you're looking at LinqToRdf you might want to look up dotNetRDF - I have an as yet unreleased port of LinqToRdf in SVN which provides for querying a much wider range of SPARQL endpoints and persisting the data back via SPARQL 1.1 Update for newer stores which support the as yet unfinished SPARQL 1.1 standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather put it the other way round: you can use an EAV store to store RDF models.

Comment: Trouble is, there are lots of existing RDF stores (triplestores) and frameworks, and I'm having trouble finding any ready-to-go EAV frameworks. So, if I'm building an EAV database then I'm wondering whether building on it on RDF framework will be a good idea.

Comment: +1 RDF is in essence an EAV model with well defined semantics

Comment: @codeulike: Ah! Well, using a full blown triple store for an EAV database seems like overkill.